# Getting map properties using react-google-maps in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-functional-component, use-ref

I am trying to access the current zoom or center of the map but I am getting some errors. I am new to React and I am not exactly sure what I am doing but I tried to attach a ref to the GoogleMap component

```
const refMap = useRef(null);

const handleZoomChanged = () => {
    const newZoom = refMap.current.getZoom();
    console.log(newZoom);
  }

...

<GoogleMap
          ref={refMap}
          {...mapProps}
          center={mapCenter}
          zoom={mapCenter.zoom}
          onZoomChanged={handleZoomChanged}
...
</GoogleMap>
```

I get one error that says: Cannot read property 'getZoom' of null and a warning that function components cannot be given refs. How can I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: What react library for Google Maps are you using? Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I referred to the samples in the [react-google-maps docs](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap) on how ref was being implemented. Please see working sample on this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-3rda9s?file=Map.js) and code snippet below:

```
import React from "react";
const { compose, withProps, withState, withHandlers } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  InfoWindow
} = require("react-google-maps");

const MapWithControlledZoom = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />
  }),
  withState("zoom", "onZoomChange", 8),
  withHandlers(() => {
    const refs = {
      map: undefined
    };

    return {
      onMapMounted: () => ref => {
        refs.map = ref;
      },
      onZoomChanged: () => () => {
        console.log(refs.map.getZoom());
        console.log(refs.map.getCenter());
      }
    };
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
    zoom={props.zoom}
    ref={props.onMapMounted}
    onZoomChanged={props.onZoomChanged}
  />
));

export default MapWithControlledZoom;
```